# Why does follow that $\eta_n\to 0$ in distribution as $n\to\infty$?

Tags: probability, cellular-automata

Following setting:

Consider $\left\{0,1,2\right\}^{\mathbb{Z}}$. And on it the following dynamics: A site $x\in \mathbb{Z}$ represents a cell which can be 1, 2 or 0. A 1 becomes a 2 in the next time step, a 2 becomes a 0 and a 0 becomes a 1 if at least one of its 2 neighbors is a 1.

Let $\eta_n(x)$ denote the state of the cell at location $x$ at time $n$.

Consider the measure space $(\left\{0,1,2\right\}^{\mathbb{Z}},\mathcal{B},P)$, where $\mathcal{B}$ is the Borel-$\sigma$-algebra generated by the cylinder sets of the form
$$
\text{cyl}(y_{i}^{i+n})=\left\{x\in\left\{0,1,2\right\}^{\mathbb{Z}}: x_i=y_i,x_{i+1}=y_{i+1},\ldots,x_{i+n}=y_{i+n}\right\}
$$
and $P$ is the product measure with
$$
P(\text{cyl}(y_i^{i+n}))=\prod_{k=i}^{i+n}p(y_k),~~\text{with}\sum_{k=0}^{2}p(k)=1.
$$

Suppose that the systems starts with $P$ giving each state the probability $1/3$.

---

Now I found the following theorem:

> > It is
> >     $$
> > \text{Prob}\left\{\eta_n(0)=1\right\}\sim\sqrt{2/(27\pi n)}, \text{where } \sim \text{ means approximately equal}.
> > $$

Furthermore, because $\text{Prob}\left\{\eta_{n+1}(0)=2\right\}=\text{Prob}\left\{\eta_n(0)=1\right\}$ it follows that
$$
\text{Prob}\left\{\eta_n(0)\neq 0\right\}\sim\sqrt{8/(27\pi n)}.
$$

---

Now to my question:

The author says that by this it follows that 
$$
\eta_n\to 0\text{ in distribution as }n\to\infty.
$$

And this is what I cannot understand.

The theorem says that eventually there will be a 0 at the cell at position 0. But why should there eventually be 0 at all cells?

Comment: This is direct from the definition of $\eta_n\to0$ in distribution and from the fact that the distribution of each $\eta_n$ is invariant by translation.

Comment: Could you please explain that? The definition of $\eta_n\to 0$ in distribution is to my knowledge that $\text{Prob}(\lim_{n\to\infty}\eta_n=0)=\text{Prob}(\left\{x:\lim_{n\to\infty}\eta_n (x)=0\right\})$. And why is the distribution of each $\eta_n$ invariant by translation?

Comment: Sorry but I am not ready to play again the drama you transformed my answers to some of your previous questions into. I posted the comment above, only to inform other math.se users.

Comment: Ok, was just interested to know whether the convergence in distribution is referred to the product measure $\text{Prob}$ on $\mathcal{B}$ or if the convergence in distribution is meant for a measure on $(\mathbb{Z},\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{Z}))$.